# how to filter data based on key in array of object in php

Tags: php, arrays, filter

i have data array

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ceklis] => 1
                [email] => john@gmail.com
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (
                [ceklis] => 0
                [email] => andrew@gmail.com
            )
    
    )
```

here I create a $data variable to hold data based on key **ceklis** = 1

```
$data = array();
$n = 0;
foreach($item as $key=>$value) {
       // how to if ceklis == 1 
        $data[]= array(
        'ceklis'    =>$item[$key],
        'email'      =>$email[$key],
     );
$n++;
}
echo "<pre>", print_r($data);
```

how to make a filter function, so that what goes into $data is the one with checklist 1

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter) method. It's taking the array and a filter method as parameters.

```php
<?php

 $array = [
    [
        'ceklis' => 1,
        'email' => 'john@gmail.com',
    ],
    [
        'ceklis' => 0,
        'email' => 'andrew@gmail.com',
    ],
  ];
$data = array_filter($array, function($a) { return $a['ceklis'] == 1;});
var_dump($data);
```

https://3v4l.org/R8OHU